# Сортировка слиянием С++. Неизвестная мне ошибка

Tags: c++

Решил написать процедуру для сортировки слиянием. Во время выполнения программы вылезает ошибка - `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1`. Так же заметил во время отладки, что значения переменных `i` и `j` вообще не имеют никакого смысла и не должны быть такими ни при каких условиях. Не могли бы вы подсказать, в чем ошибка?

```
void merge(vector<int> mainv)
{
    vector<int> a, b;
    a.insert(a.begin(), mainv.begin(), mainv.begin() + mainv.size()/2);
    b.insert(b.begin(), mainv.begin() + mainv.size()/2, mainv.end());
    if(a.size() > 1)
        merge(a);
    if(b.size() > 1)
        merge(b);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i != a.size() || j != b.size())
    {
        if(a[i] < b[j])
        {
            mainv.push_back(a[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            mainv.push_back(b[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(i == a.size())
        mainv.insert(mainv.end(), b.begin() + j, b.end());
    else
        mainv.insert(mainv.end(), a.begin() + i, a.end());
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, условие продолжения цикла слияния `i != a.size() || j != b.size()` вкупе с тем, что происходит внутри цикла в вашей реализации, не предотвращает выхода одного из индексов за пределы массива. Что у вас и происходит.

Правильную реализацию можно сделать с разными вариантами условия цикла, но если принять во внимание то, что у вас после цикла сделана выделенная обработка оставшегося "хвоста" массива, в самом цикле вам, очевидно, нужно именно условие

```
while (i != a.size() && j != b.size())
```

Именно `&&`, а не `||`.

Во-вторых, вектор `mainv` у вас передается в функцию *по значению*. Модификации этого вектора, сделанные внутри функции, никак не попадут наружу. Это бессмысленно. Ваши вызовы `merge(a)` и `merge(b)` не будут сортировать векторы `a` и `b` в том числе и по этой причине. Предавать вектор в функцию надо бы *по ссылке*

```
void merge(vector<int> &mainv)
```

Опять же, тут можно поступить и по-другому, но очевидно ваша изначальная задумка требует именно этого.

В-третьих, по вашей задумке надо было бы почистить вектор `mainv` после разбиения его на `a` и `b`, т.е. перед вставкой элементов обратно.

---

**P.S.** Альтернативной реализацией цикла будет реализация с именно вашим исходным вариантом условия и *без* обработки хвостов после цикла

```
while (i != a.size() || j != b.size())
{
    if (i != a.size() && a[i] < b[j])
    {
        mainv.push_back(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        mainv.push_back(b[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Но ваш вариант с выделенной обработкой "хвоста" мне лично нравится больше (после исправления условия, разумеется) .